# Divide an unsigned long for a size_t and assign the result to a double

Tags: c++, c++11, precision, arbitrary-precision

I have to divide an unsigned long int  for a size_t (returned from a dimension of a array with size() ) like this:

```
vector<string> mapped_samples;
vector<double> mean;
vector<unsigned long> feature_sum;
/* elaboration here */
mean.at(index) = feature_sum.at(index) /mapped_samples.size();
```

but in this way an integer division takes place (I lose the decimal part. That's no good)

Therefore, I can do:

```
 mean.at(index) = feature_sum.at(index) / double(mapped_samples.size());
```

But in this way `feature_sum.at(index)` is automatically converted (Temporary copy) to `double` and I could lose precision. How can I tackle the question? I have to use some library?

It could be precision loss when you convert the unsigned long in double (because the unsigned long value could be larger than maximum double) The unsigned long value is the sum of the features (positives values). The samples of feature can be 1000000 or more and the sum of values of the features can be enourmus. The max value of a feature is 2000 thus: 2000*1000000 or more

(I'm using C++11)

Comment: You could use the [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) library; it's capable of arbitrary-precision integer and floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @JasonR In C++ there isn't a simpler solution? I'm focused on other now and I I would not study a library for a single operation Unless it is the only way

Comment: You have not specified what precision you need

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: you said that the `size_t` represents the dimension of an array, but you're concerned about loss of precision when converting it to a `double`. A `double` can hold 53-bit integers without any loss of precision. Do you really need to support values larger than `2^53 - 1`?

Comment: @JasonR It could be precision loss when you convert the unsigned long in double (because the unsigned long value could  be larger than maximum double)  The unsigned long value is the sum of the features (positives values). The samples of feature can be 1000000 or more and the sum of values of the features can be enourmus. The max value of a feature is 2000 thus: 2000*1000000 or more

Comment: @Umbert: The maxium unsigned long value is ~2^64, while the maximum double is ~2^300. There is no issue with ranges.

Comment: 2000*1000000 is only a ten digit number.  2^53 is a sixteen digit number.  You've got a ways to go before you have to worry about losing precision.

Comment: @MooingDuck  I know that the maximum length of types of C ++ isn't standard. What guarantees that it always happens that a double is larger than an unsigned long?

Comment: Unless you're working on an exotic platform, a `double` will always be defined by the IEEE-754 standard, so its range is explicitly specified. Based on that and the description of what the `size_t` value that you have represents, you shouldn't need to worry about precision loss when converting to a `double`. I would wager that it will be a long time before you'll ever have an array with a dimension that is comparable to `2^53` in size.

Comment: @jameslarge and in general on any compiler and any system the maximum double of C++ have 16 digits?

Comment: @JasonR and james are right. double is 8 byte almost everywhere, and this is ok in my case. Thanks

Comment: @Umbert, The vast majority of hardware and software floating point systems conform to the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).  In C/C++ "float" usually means the IEEE 754 binary32 format, and "double" usually means the binary64 format, which gives you your 16 digits of precision.  If your system supports "long double", it might not be a non-IEEE format, but it almost certainly will have more than 16 digits of precision.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use [`std::div`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div)

Along the lines

```
auto dv = std::div(feature_sum.at(index), mapped_samples.size());

double mean = dv.quot + dv.rem / double(mapped_samples.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
// Grab the integral part of the division
auto v1 = feature_sum.at(index)/mapped_samples.size();

// Grab the remainder of the division
auto v2 = feature_sum.at(index)%mapped_samples.size();

// Dividing 1.0*v2 is unlikely to lose precision
mean.at(index) = v1 + static_cast<double>(v2)/mapped_samples.size();
```

Comment: same as std::div version

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, true.

Comment: Is this any more precise than the original?

Comment: The usage of `1.0*v2/mapped_samples.size()` shows that you're pretty confident on knowing your operator preferences etc. Safer and more readable is `double(v2)/mapped_samples.size()`.

Comment: @MooingDuck, yes. You are more likely to lose precision when converting `feature_sum.at(index)` to `double` than converting `v2` to `double`.

Comment: @RSahu I disagree, see my answer.

Comment: @Walter, I took a cursory glance at your answer but didn't quite grok it. It sounds like you have dealt with this aspect of floating point numbers more than I have.

Answer (score 2):

**you cannot do better** (if you want to store the result as a `double`), than the simple

```
std::uint64_t x=some_value, y=some_other_value;
auto mean = double(x)/double(y);
```

because the relative accuracy of the truncated form of the correct result using [`float128`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html)

```
auto improved = double(float128(x)/float128(x))
```

is typically the same (for typical input -- there may be rare inputs, where improvement is possible). Both have a relative error dictated by the length of the mantissa for `double` (53 bits). So the simple answer is: either use a more accurate type than `double` for your mean or forget about this issue.

---

To see the relative accuracy, let us assume that

```
x=a*(1+e);   // a=double(x)
y=b*(1+f);   // b=double(y)
```

where `e`, `f` are of the order 2^-53.

Then the 'correct' quotient is to first order in `e` and `f`

```
(x/y) = (a/b) * (1 + e - f)
```

Converting this to `double` incurs another relative error of the order of 2^-53, i.e. of the same order as the the error of `(a/b)`, the result of the naive

```
mean = double(x)/double(y).
```

Of course, `e` and `f` can conspire to cancel, when more accuracy can be gained by the methods suggested in other answers, but typically the accuracy cannot be improved.